# How to design database for personalized voting

Tags: database, database-design, postgresql, twitter, relational-database

I wonder how to create something like is doing twitter, but in relational databases.

> One application of FlockDB that Weil
>   cites is determining which users to
>   show @ replies to. For example, if
>   Ashton Kutcher sends a tweet to
>   @foursquare, it shouldn't show up for
>   all of Kutcher's 6,156,915 followers.
>   It should show up only for users that
>   follow both Kutcher and Foursquare.

Comment: How to design a db for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with database design, but with how you query the database.

You definitely store each @follow at separate table, there you will have fields **who tweets** and **who is replied**. Than you will show the user X all @follows, in which both tweeting and replied is in set of people who he follows :)